# How to import multiple excel files using a macro in python xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I need to automate a code where I am importing multiple excel files using `xlwings`. I have the code for importing a single excel file.

```py
import xlwings as xw
WB = xw.book('book1.xlsx')
DF= WB.sheets['sheet1'].used_range.options(pd.DataFrame, header= True).value

WB1 = xw.book('book2.xlsx')
DF1= WB.sheets['sheet1'].used_range.options(pd.DataFrame, header= True).value

append=pd.DataFrame().append([DF,DF1])

append.to_excel('combined.xlsx')
```

In this way I need to import all the files and save the appended file. I have to use `xlwings` only for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Python lists:

```
import xlwings as xw

filenames = ['book1.xlsx', 'book2.xlsx', 'book3.xlsx']
contents = []
for filename in filenames:
    wb = xw.book(filename)
    df = wb.sheets['sheet1'].used_range.options(
                    pd.DataFrame, header= True).value
    contents.append(df)

append = pd.DataFrame().append(contents)
append.to_excel('combined.xlsx')
```